# wpdb hace consultas en orden incorrecto

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, wordpress

tengo un problema con el procesamiento de un fichero. Primero os hago un resumen de la situación.

La idea es recibir en un csv los precios de 3 tipos de habitaciones para una fecha en concreto (una línea para cada día), y con ese fichero yo debo hacer los insert en las tablas correspondientes del plugin de reservas que hemos elegido (hbook).

Estos datos van a ir a 5 tablas:

- seasons: aquí van las temporadas. Solo guarda ID y nombre.
- season_dates: aquí se guardan las fechas de inicio y fin de cada temporada y los días de la semana a los que se aplica.
- rates: precios. los datos que nos importan aquí son ID de precio y cuantía.
- rates_season: precio para cada temporada. Se guarda el id del precio y el de la temporada.
- rates_accom: precio para cada habitación.

Primero intenté usar transacciones por si en algún momento del proceso algo iba mal, dejar los datos como antes de iniciarlo todo pero no recuerdo porqué tuve que desecharlo, ahora estoy intentando montar tablas temporales donde cargar los datos y al final si todo ha ido bien borro las tablas originales y renombro las temporales con el nombre original.

El fichero csv que tengo que procesar: https://pastebin.com/16Ng4t6X

El código:

```
class Debug{
    public function Print_rr($flag = true){
        if(_DEBUG_){
            echo "<pre>".print_r($this, $flag)."</pre>";
        }
    }

    public static function WriteLog($line, $msg = 'test'){          
        if(_DEBUG_){
            $file = _PLUGIN_PATH_ . 'log/log.txt';          
            $errorMessage = "[".date("d-m-Y H:i:s")."] $line | ";

            if(!is_object($msg) && !is_array($msg)){
                $errorMessage .= $msg;
            }
            else{
                $errorMessage .= print_r($msg, true);
            }

            error_log("$errorMessage\n", 3, $file);
        }
    }

}



function ProcessFileTari($tarifaPath){
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    global $wpdb;

    try{
        $wpdb->flush();

        $ok = DebugQuery(__LINE__, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_."` (
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;");

        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._SEASONS_DATES_TEMPTABLE_."` (
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `season_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        `start_date` date NOT NULL,
        `end_date` date NOT NULL,
        `days` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;");

        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._RATES_SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_."` (
        `rate_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        `season_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;");

        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._RATES_TEMPTABLE_."` (
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `type` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
        `all_accom` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
        `all_seasons` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
        `amount` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL,
        `nights` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;");

        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._RATES_ACCOM_TEMPTABLE_."` (
        `rate_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        `accom_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;");

        if(!$ok){
            Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "no ok creacion tablas temporales");
        }

        $ok = $ok && false !== DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'TRUNCATE '._SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_.';');
        $ok = $ok && false !== DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'TRUNCATE '._SEASONS_DATES_TEMPTABLE_.';');
        $ok = $ok && false !== DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'TRUNCATE '._RATES_SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_.';');
        $ok = $ok && false !== DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'TRUNCATE '._RATES_TEMPTABLE_.';');
        $ok = $ok && false !== DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'TRUNCATE '._RATES_ACCOM_TEMPTABLE_.';');

        if(!$ok){
            Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "no ok vaciado tablas originales");
        }

        $handle = fopen($tarifaPath, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            $prevLine = array('', 0, 0, 0);
            $firstLoop = true;

            $precioInd = 0; //individuales
            $precioDtr = 0; //dobles
            $precioTri = 0; //triples
            $startDate = '';
            $endDate = '';


            $sql = "SELECT post_id, meta_value, (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'ex_accomodation_supplement' AND post_id = pm.post_id) AS supplement";
            $sql.= "  FROM wp_postmeta pm";
            $sql.= " WHERE meta_key = 'ex_accomodation_code'";
            $sql.= "   AND post_id IN (SELECT id";
            $sql.= "                     FROM wp_posts";
            $sql.= "                    WHERE post_type = 'hb_accommodation'";
            $sql.= "                      AND post_status = 'publish');";
            $accomCodesOArray = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            $accomCodes = array();

            foreach($accomCodesOArray as $code){
                $data = new stdClass();
                $data->post_id = $code->post_id;
                $data->supplement = $code->supplement != null ? $code->supplement : 0;
                $accomCodes[$code->meta_value] = $data;
            }
            //Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, print_r($accomCodes, true));
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false && $ok) {
                $datos = explode(";", $line);

                $precioInd = $datos[1]; //individuals
                $precioDtr = $datos[2]; //dobles
                $precioTri = $datos[3]; //triples

                if($firstLoop){
                    $startDate = $datos[0];
                    $firstLoop = false;
                }
                else{
                    if($precioInd == $prevLine[1] && $precioDtr == $prevLine[2] && $precioTri == $prevLine[3]){
                        //same season
                        $endDate = $datos[0];
                    }
                    else{
                        //new season
                        $ok = $ok && InsertSeasonData($startDate, $endDate, $accomCodes, $precioInd, $precioDtr, $precioTri);
                        if(!$ok){
                            Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "no ok una de las season");
                        }
                        $startDate = $datos[0];
                        $endDate = $datos[0];
                    }
                }

                $prevLine = $datos;
            }

            $ok = $ok && InsertSeasonData($startDate, $endDate, $accomCodes, $precioInd, $precioDtr, $precioTri);

            if($ok){
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._SEASONS_DATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._RATES_SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._RATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._RATES_ACCOM_TABLE_.'`;', true);

                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._SEASONS_DATES_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._SEASONS_DATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._RATES_SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._RATES_SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._RATES_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._RATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                //$ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._RATES_ACCOM_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._RATES_ACCOM_TABLE_.'`;', true);
                Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "Ahora tocaria borrar y renombrar las tablas");
            }
            else{
                Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "no ok ultima season");
            }

            fclose($handle);
            if(!_DEBUG_){
                unlink($tarifaPath);
            }
        } 
        else{
            update_option('hbook_ex_errorTarifaFile', json_encode($handle, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, 'Excepción capturada procesando tarifa.csv: '.print_r($e->getMessage(), true));
        Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, print_r($e, true));
    }
    Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "Elapsed time is: ". (microtime(true) - $startTime) ." seconds");
    //test_transaction();
}

function InsertSeasonData($startDate, $endDate, $accomCodes, $precioInd, $precioDtr, $precioTri){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush();
    $ok = true;
    $seasonName = str_replace("/", "", $startDate) . "-" . str_replace("/", "", $endDate);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . _SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_ . " (`name`) VALUES ('$seasonName');";
    $ok = DebugQuery(__LINE__, $sql);
    $seasonId = $wpdb->insert_id;

    if($ok){
        $startDateFormatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $startDate)->format('Y-m-d');
        $endDateFormatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $endDate)->format('Y-m-d');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . _SEASONS_DATES_TEMPTABLE_ . " (`season_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `days`) ";
        $sql.= "VALUES ($seasonId, '$startDateFormatted', '$endDateFormatted', '0,1,2,3,4,5,6');";
        $ok = DebugQuery(__LINE__, $sql);

        if($ok){
            foreach($accomCodes as $key => $accom){
                $price = 0;
                switch($key){
                    case "IND":
                        $price = $precioInd + $accom->supplement;
                        break;

                    case "DAL":
                    case "DMA":
                    case "DMT":
                        $price = $precioDtr + $accom->supplement;
                        break;

                    case "DPT":
                    case "DTR":
                        $price = $precioTri + $accom->supplement;
                        break;
                }

                $sql ="INSERT INTO " . _RATES_TEMPTABLE_ . " (`type`, `all_accom`, `all_seasons`, `amount`, `nights`) ";
                $sql.="VALUES ('accom', 0, 0, $price, 1);";
                $ok = DebugQuery(__LINE__, $sql);
                $rateId = $wpdb->insert_id;

                $sql ="INSERT INTO " . _RATES_SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_ . " (`rate_id`, `season_id`) VALUES ($rateId, $seasonId);";
                $ok = DebugQuery(__LINE__, $sql);

                $sql ="INSERT INTO " . _RATES_ACCOM_TEMPTABLE_ . " (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES ($rateId, {$accom->post_id})";
                $ok = DebugQuery(__LINE__, $sql);
                $tete = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $ok;
}

function DebugQuery($line, $sql, $warnAdmin = false){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush();
    $ok = $wpdb->query($sql);
    Debug::WriteLog($line, "Resultado: $ok - $sql");

    if(!$ok){
        Debug::WriteLog($line, $wpdb->last_error);
        if($warnAdmin){
            $to = "msolla@extrasoft.es";
            $subject = "Error MySQL Hotel Acueducto";

            Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "Mailing error to $to:" . wp_mail($to, $subject, $wpdb->last_error));
        }
    }
    return $ok;
}
```

Con el código así, la última línea en mi fichero log es la de "536 | Ahora tocaria borrar y renombrar las tablas", es decir, justo lo esperado.

Pero si cambio el final y descomento los drop y los rename, las últimas líneas del log van desordenadas y claro, da errores de bbdd:

```
    if($ok){
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._SEASONS_DATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._RATES_SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._RATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'DROP TABLE `'._RATES_ACCOM_TABLE_.'`;', true);

        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._SEASONS_DATES_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._SEASONS_DATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._RATES_SEASONS_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._RATES_SEASONS_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._RATES_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._RATES_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        $ok = $ok && DebugQuery(__LINE__, 'RENAME TABLE `'._RATES_ACCOM_TEMPTABLE_.'` TO `'._RATES_ACCOM_TABLE_.'`;', true);
        //Debug::WriteLog(__LINE__, "Ahora tocaria borrar y renombrar las tablas");
    }
```

Log (últimas líneas):

```
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 604 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_accom (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES (2561, 560)
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 604 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_accom (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES (2562, 612)
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 523 | Resultado: 1 - DROP TABLE `wp_hb_seasons`;
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 597 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates (`type`, `all_accom`, `all_seasons`, `amount`, `nights`) VALUES ('accom', 0, 0, 90, 1);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 524 | Resultado: 1 - DROP TABLE `wp_hb_seasons_dates`;
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 525 | Resultado: 1 - DROP TABLE `wp_hb_rates_seasons`;
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 526 | Resultado: 1 - DROP TABLE `wp_hb_rates`;
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 527 | Resultado: 1 - DROP TABLE `wp_hb_rates_accom`;
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 601 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_seasons (`rate_id`, `season_id`) VALUES (2563, 427);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 604 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_accom (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES (2563, 563)
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 597 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates (`type`, `all_accom`, `all_seasons`, `amount`, `nights`) VALUES ('accom', 0, 0, 85, 1);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 529 | Resultado: 0 - RENAME TABLE `wp_temp_seasons` TO `wp_hb_seasons`;
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 529 | 
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 601 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_seasons (`rate_id`, `season_id`) VALUES (2564, 427);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 625 | Mailing error to msolla@extrasoft.es:
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 553 | Elapsed time is: 8.24390721321 seconds
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 604 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_accom (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES (2564, 564)
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 597 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates (`type`, `all_accom`, `all_seasons`, `amount`, `nights`) VALUES ('accom', 0, 0, 90, 1);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 601 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_seasons (`rate_id`, `season_id`) VALUES (2565, 427);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 604 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_accom (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES (2565, 565)
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 597 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates (`type`, `all_accom`, `all_seasons`, `amount`, `nights`) VALUES ('accom', 0, 0, 45, 1);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 601 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_seasons (`rate_id`, `season_id`) VALUES (2566, 427);
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 604 | Resultado: 1 - INSERT INTO wp_temp_rates_accom (`rate_id`, `accom_id`) VALUES (2566, 612)
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 564 | Resultado:  - INSERT INTO wp_temp_seasons (`name`) VALUES ('31102018-01112018');
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 564 | Table 'hotextra_segovia.wp_temp_seasons' doesn't exist
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 510 | no ok una de las season
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 537 | no ok ultima season
[07-11-2017 08:01:22] 553 | Elapsed time is: 7.65954709053 seconds
```

El select que llena la variable $accomCodesOArray y que uso para llenar el array $accomCodes es correcto y da este resultado:
561 DMA 15
560 DAL null
563 DTR null
564 DMT null
565 DPT null
612 IND null

Gracias.

Comment: No terminé de entender el problema, pero me parece que has elegido un camina largo cuando podías hacerlo más corto. Me refiero a esto que dices: *Primero intenté usar transacciones por si en algún momento del proceso algo iba mal, dejar los datos como antes de iniciarlo todo pero no recuerdo porqué tuve que desecharlo, **ahora estoy intentando montar tablas temporales donde cargar los datos y al final si todo ha ido bien borro las tablas originales y renombro las temporales con el nombre original**.* A nivel de rendimiento y de todo esto es una barbaridad.

Comment: El problema es que no entiendo porqué en el log se registran intentos de insert después de los drop, en teoría el código está pensado para que haga todos los insert y al acabar haga los drop y los rename.

Comment: Algo extraño que veo es que haces inserts dentro de la lectura del archivo y luego haces otro insert al salir de la lectura del archivo... Dado que es un código algo complejo, sugeriría que escribieses algo sencillo con la lógica global de tu programa, con echos en cada bloque de código... que pruebes eso y cuando funcione entonces que pongas en cada bloque lo que corresponda. Creo que analizar todo ese código es imposible sin conocer el contexto en que intentas hacerlo funcionar.